# How do I get debuild to put the binary in /usr/bin?

Tags: packaging

I have been recently trying to package a small Python utility to put on my PPA and I've almost got it to work, but I'm having problems in making the package install the binary (a chmod +x Python script) under `/usr/bin`. Instead it installs under `/`. I have this directory structure -> http://db.tt/0KhIYQL.

My package Makefile is like so:

```
TARGET=usr/bin/txtrevise

make:
      chmod +x $(TARGET)

install:
      cp -r $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)
```

I've used `$(DESTDIR)`, as I understand it to place the file under the `debian` subdir when `debuild` is run.

I have the txtrevise script, my executable, under `usr/bin` folder under the root of my package. I also have the `Makefile` and `usr/bin/textrevise` in my tarball: txtrevise_1.1.original.tar.gz.

However when I build this and look inside of the Debian package, txtrevise is always at the root of the package instead of under `usr/bin` and will be installed to `/` instead of `/usr/bin`.

How can I get `debuild` to put the script in the right place?

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DESTDIR` environment variable is defined in the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html):

> `DESTDIR` is a variable prepended to each installed target file.
>
> ...
>
> If your installation step would normally install
>   `/usr/local/bin/foo` and `/usr/local/lib/libfoo.a`, then an
>   installation invoked as in the example above would install
>   `/tmp/stage/usr/local/bin/foo` and `/tmp/stage/usr/local/lib/libfoo.a`
>   instead.
>
> Prepending the variable `DESTDIR` to each target in this way
>   provides for "staged installs", where the installed files are not
>   placed directly into their expected location but are instead copied
>   into a temporary location (`DESTDIR`).  However, installed files
>   maintain their relative directory structure and any embedded file names
>   will not be modified.

This is the way the debhelper scripts expect your make file to behave.  So if you want your program to appear in `/usr/bin` when the package is installed, then you should copy the program to `$(DESTDIR)/usr/bin` (creating that directory structure if it doesn't exist).